# Interlocked and Memory Barriers

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, lock-free

I have a question about the following code sample (*m_value* isn't volatile, and every thread runs on a separate processor)

```
void Foo() // executed by thread #1, BEFORE Bar() is executed
{
   Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_value, 1);
}

bool Bar() // executed by thread #2, AFTER Foo() is executed
{
   return m_value == 1;
}
```

Does using *Interlocked.Exchange* in Foo() guarantees that when Bar() is executed, I'll see the value "1"? (even if the value already exists in a register or cache line?) Or do I need to place a memory barrier before reading the value of *m_value*?

Also (unrelated to the original question), is it legal to declare a volatile member and pass it by reference to *InterlockedXX* methods? (the compiler warns about passing volatiles by reference, so should I ignore the warning in such case?)

**Please Note**, I'm not looking for "better ways to do things", so please don't post answers that suggest completely alternate ways to do things ("use a lock instead" etc.), this question comes out of pure interest..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual pattern for memory barrier usage matches what you would put in the implementation of a critical section, but split into pairs for the producer and consumer.  As an example your critical section implementation would typically be of the form:

```
while (!pShared->lock.testAndSet_Acquire()) ;
// (this loop should include all the normal critical section stuff like
// spin, waste, 
// pause() instructions, and last-resort-give-up-and-blocking on a resource 
// until the lock is made available.)

// Access to shared memory.

pShared->foo = 1 
v = pShared-> goo

pShared->lock.clear_Release()
```

Acquire memory barrier above makes sure that any loads (pShared->goo) that may have been started before the successful lock modification are tossed, to be restarted if neccessary.

The release memory barrier ensures that the load from goo into the (local say) variable v is complete before the lock word protecting the shared memory is cleared.

You have a similar pattern in the typical producer and consumer atomic flag scenerio (it is difficult to tell by your sample if that is what you are doing but should illustrate the idea).

Suppose your producer used an atomic variable to indicate that some other state is ready to use.  You'll want something like this:

```
pShared->goo = 14

pShared->atomic.setBit_Release()
```

Without a "write" barrier here in the producer you have no guarantee that the hardware isn't going to get to the atomic store before the goo store has made it through the cpu store queues, and up through the memory hierarchy where it is visible (even if you have a mechanism that ensures the compiler orders things the way you want).

In the consumer

```
if ( pShared->atomic.compareAndSwap_Acquire(1,1) )
{
   v = pShared->goo 
}
```

Without a "read" barrier here you won't know that the hardware hasn't gone and fetched goo for you before the atomic access is complete.  The atomic (ie: memory manipulated with the Interlocked functions doing stuff like lock cmpxchg), is only "atomic" with respect to itself, not other memory.

Now, the remaining thing that has to be mentioned is that the barrier constructs are highly unportable.  Your compiler probably provides _acquire and _release variations for most of the atomic manipulation methods, and these are the sorts of ways you would use them.  Depending on the platform you are using (ie: ia32), these may very well be exactly what you would get without the _acquire() or _release() suffixes.  Platforms where this matters are ia64 (effectively dead except on HP where its still twitching slightly), and powerpc.  ia64 had .acq and .rel instruction modifiers on most load and store instructions (including the atomic ones like cmpxchg).  powerpc has separate instructions for this (isync and lwsync give you the read and write barriers respectively).

Now.  Having said all this.  Do you really have a good reason for going down this path?  Doing all this correctly can be very difficult.  Be prepared for a lot of self doubt and insecurity in code reviews and make sure you have a lot of high concurrency testing with all sorts of random timing scenerios.  Use a critical section unless you have a very very good reason to avoid it, and don't write that critical section yourself.

Comment: great answer, thanks (just for the sake of interest.. multithreaded and lock free programming is a very interesting topic, so I'm exploring this area.. [btw, do you have recommendations about any good books about these topics? [besides Joe Duffy's book ..]])

Comment: I don't actually know joe duffy's book ... everything I've learned on the subject was "on the job".  I get a lot of questions on the topic having originally coded our product's lock-free implementation of reader-writer mutexes, and all the inline assembly for our product's atomic interfaces (before the days where the compilers provided nice intrinsics for this like they do now).  The best I have for references is here:

http://sites.google.com/site/peeterjoot/math2009/atomic.pdf

... it's just the references for a paper on the topic I've never actually gotten to writing:)

Comment: (that url now has more than links but I can't promise the content is coherent;)

Answer (score 5):

Memory barriers don't particularly help you. They specify an ordering between memory operations, in this case each thread only has one memory operation so it doesn't matter. One typical scenario is writing non-atomically to fields in a structure, a memory barrier, then publishing the address of the structure to other threads. The Barrier guarantees that the writes to the structures members are seen by all CPUs before they get the address of it.

What you really need are atomic operations, ie. InterlockedXXX functions, or volatile variables in C#. If the read in Bar were atomic, you could guarantee that neither the compiler, nor the cpu, does any optimizations that prevent it from reading either the value before the write in Foo, or after the write in Foo depending on which gets executed first. Since you are saying that you "know" Foo's write happens before Bar's read, then Bar would always return true.

Without the read in Bar being atomic, it could be reading a partially updated value (ie. garbage), or a cached value (either from the compiler or from the CPU), both of which may prevent Bar from returning true which it should.

Most modern CPU's guarantee word aligned reads are atomic, so the real trick is that you have to tell the compiler that the read is atomic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure but I think the Interlocked.Exchange will use the [InterlockedExchange function of the windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683590(VS.85).aspx) that provides a full memory barrier anyway.

> This function generates a full memory
>   barrier (or fence) to ensure that
>   memory operations are completed in
>   order.

Comment: Does it matter that the memory barrier was used in thread #1 when the value was written, but not on thread #2 when the value is read?

Comment: it does matter - you need a barrier on the reading thread, else the read thread might re-order some other reads before the read to m_value.

ie
    if (m_value)
    {
        Foo foo = important_shared_data;
    }

If you don't want important_shared_data read early, then you need read/acquire barrier on m_value. (And release on write).

If you don't other have data dependent on m_value, then you probably don't need the barriers at all - but how often do you have data that isn't dependent on other things?  ie is m_value useless?

Answer (score 1):

The interlocked exchange operations guarantee a memory barrier.

> The following synchronization functions use the appropriate barriers
>   to ensure memory ordering:
>
> - Functions that enter or leave critical sections
> - Functions that signal synchronization objects
> - Wait functions
> - Interlocked functions

(Source : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686355%28VS.85%29.aspx))

But you are out of luck with register variables. If m_value is in a register in Bar, you won't see the change to m_value. Due to this, you should declare shared variables 'volatile'.

Comment: Is that a block quote from another source?  If so, a citation would be good.

Comment: Link added. Was copied from a local MSDN.

Comment: So, you are saying that you need a memory barrier on your reads. What if you use interlocked to update it and just put a `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` before your read in the loop? That should be enough, right?

Answer (score 1):

If `m_value` is not marked as `volatile`, then there is no reason to think that the value read in `Bar` is fenced. Compiler optimizations, caching, or other factors could reorder the reads and writes. Interlocked exchange is only helpful when it is used in an ecosystem of properly fenced memory references. This is the whole point of marking a field `volatile`. The .Net memory model is not as straight forward as some might expect.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to mark m_value as volatile and pass it by reference to the Interlocked method? (though the compiler warns about it .. though it seems meaningless in such case)

Comment: Yes, in this case it is safe to ignore the compiler warning. Passing the variable (by reference) to any method other than the interlocked methods would be a problem, but for the interlocked methods it's OK.

Comment: If the variable is marked volatile, then (in C#, NOT C++) the compiler will add acquire/release barriers as needed, so InterLocked is not usually necessary. (ie Interlocked gives full barrier, volatile gives acquire on read, release on write,  Typically that's all you need).

Comment: Volatile is not an alternative to Interlocked.Exchange(), because it does not ensure atomic sequences of read and write operations. Volatile only ensures that the operations will not be reordered.

Comment: Since .net guarantees reference reads/writes are atomic, isn’t `volatile` enough if you *don’t* need to read `Interlocked.Exchange()`’s return value? The interlocked is only useful because it gives you the ability to inspect the prior value or make the write conditional without having to use `lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Interlocked.Exchange() should guarantee that the value is flushed to all CPUs properly - it provides its own memory barrier.

I'm surprised that the compiler is complaing about passing a volatile into Interlocked.Exchange() - the fact that you're using Interlocked.Exchange() should almost mandate a volatile variable.

The problem you *might* see is that if the compiler does some heavy optimization of Bar() and realizes that nothing changes the value of m_value it can optimize away your check.  That's what the volatile keyword would do - it would hint to the compiler that that variable may be changed outside of the optimizer's view.

Comment: but is the barrier place before/after the assignment? (or both?)

Comment: Image that it happens "with" the assignment.
For reads (acquires), the read is added to the read queue, then the CPU waits for the read queue to be flushed before adding anything else to it.
This way, subsequent reads (as listed in code) don't get reordered (inside the read queue) before your important read of m_value.
For writes, the write queue is flushed first, then the write of m_value is queued.  This way writes don't happen after the write to m_value.
For full barriers, both queues are flushed.
Note, again, that the important part is how the value is ordered relative to other values...

Comment: @Aaron: re "flushed to all CPUs" - a single sided barrier (ie only from one CPU) is not enough.  The reading CPUs need to have barriers to prevent reads from being re-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't tell the compiler or runtime that `m_value` should not be read ahead of Bar(), it can and may cache the value of `m_value` ahead of `Bar()` and simply use the cached value. If you want to ensure that it sees the "latest" version of `m_value`, either shove in a `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` or use `Thread.VolatileRead(ref m_value)`. The latter is less expensive than a full memory barrier.

Ideally you could shove in a ReadBarrier, but the CLR doesn't seem to support that directly.

EDIT: Another way to think about it is that there are really two kinds of memory barriers: compiler memory barriers that tell the compiler how to sequence reads and writes and CPU memory barriers that tell the CPU how to sequence reads and writes. The `Interlocked` functions use CPU memory barriers. Even if the compiler treated them as compiler memory barriers, it still wouldn't matter, as in this specific case, `Bar()` could have been separately compiled and not known of the other uses of `m_value` that would require a compiler memory barrier.

Comment: how come Thread.VoltileRead is less expensive? according to Reflector, it still uses a full fence (actually calling MemoryBarrier)

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation, but according to the documentation (eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645755(VS.71).aspx) VolatileRead just does an AcquireBarrier (ie 'half-barrier', whereas Interlocked and/or MemoryBarrier does a full barrier.  So VolatileRead could be less expensive.  However, on some/most Intel platforms, all the barriers are implemented as full barriers anyhow.

Comment: But again, there's a difference between a processor barrier and a compiler barrier. In this particular case, you at least want a compiler barrier.